# how to generate Jmeter CSV report just with defined regular expression variables

Tags: jmeter

Is it possible to get a CSV file report in JMeter just with only defined regular expression variables values from all the samplers?
Because I have defined sample_variables in JMeter user.properties file. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The easiest way is using [Flexible File Writer](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FlexibleFileWriter/)
2. A little bit harder - suppress all JMeter default result saving configuration via *user.properties* file like:

   ```
   jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=csv
   jmeter.save.saveservice.assertion_results_failure_message=false
   jmeter.save.saveservice.assertion_results=none
   jmeter.save.saveservice.data_type=false
   jmeter.save.saveservice.label=false
   jmeter.save.saveservice.response_code=false
   jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=false
   jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data.on_error=false
   jmeter.save.saveservice.response_message=false
   jmeter.save.saveservice.successful=false
   jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_name=false
   jmeter.save.saveservice.time=false
   jmeter.save.saveservice.subresults=false
   jmeter.save.saveservice.assertions=false
   jmeter.save.saveservice.latency=false
   jmeter.save.saveservice.connect_time=false
   jmeter.save.saveservice.samplerData=false
   jmeter.save.saveservice.responseHeaders=false
   jmeter.save.saveservice.requestHeaders=false
   jmeter.save.saveservice.encoding=false
   jmeter.save.saveservice.bytes=false
   jmeter.save.saveservice.url=false
   jmeter.save.saveservice.filename=false
   jmeter.save.saveservice.hostname=false
   jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_counts=false
   jmeter.save.saveservice.sample_count=false
   jmeter.save.saveservice.idle_time=false
   jmeter.save.saveservice.print_field_names=false
   ```
3. Hardest: add i.e. [Beanshell Listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Listener) to write variable value to a separate file. Example code is something like:

   ```
   import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

   FileUtils.writeStringToFile(new File("target_file.csv",vars.get("your_variable_name")));
   ```

   See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for more information regarding bypassing JMeter limitations using scripting

Comment: Thank you very much for providing different options. I would like to get 3 reports as follows. 1. View Results in Tree, 2. Summary Report, 3. Separate Report just with the defined regular exp.variables. I'm not sure whether I will be able to generate all 3 reports in 3 different CSV files. In the 3rd report just with defined variables, I need to programmatically calculate difference in two variable values that are actually time stamps. I appreciate if you can provide any clue for this? thanks again.

Comment: 1. You don't need 3 reports, 1 .jtl file can be used in multiple listeners. 2. You can use [__intSum() function](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii) to get difference between 2 variables into 3rd variable and store it into .jtl file via [Sample Variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables) property.

Comment: Thank you @Dmitri. 1.jtl file is helping me with my requirement, 2. I've time stamp in this format '2016-06-24T18:22:52.918Z' and I used ${_longSum(completionDate, -startDate)} as regular expo or user variable. Both of them did not help me. Am I missing some format here? Yes I defined 3rd variable and added into my user.properties file. Thanks

Comment: I just read since UTC timeStamp that I'm getting is having float value I can not use any of the __intSum() and __longSum() functions right?